# How can I have 2 plots side by side such that I can show a line going from one to the other?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's a quick visual link to what I want to show,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVvGqWyQB_0&index=2&list=PL5563BAB9EA968641

at 6:09.

I've tried using minipages but that won't allow for a line to go from one plot to the other and here is the code for one of the plots,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
ticks=none,
axis lines = middle,
axis line style={->},
ymin=-0.5, ymax = 2.5,
xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
axis equal image
]
\draw (axis cs:1.25,1.25) circle [blue, radius=0.5];
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node[above left] {$a$};
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node{$\bullet$};
\draw [->] (axis cs:1.25,1.25)  -- node[pos = 0.5, below] {$\delta$} (axis cs:1.75,1.25) ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I'll add it sorry.

Comment: You can have multiple `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture`, placed at different locations with the `at` key. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289079/2x2-array-of-pgf-plots/289087#289087

Comment: In addition to what @TorbjørnT. is saying, you could use `remember picture` to remember the coordinates in a given picture. You can then access them with `overlay,remember picture` in a separate picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create several `axis` environments and shift them with `xshift`.
Then, simply draw an arrow from one to the other.

[image: axis]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
ticks=none,
axis lines = middle,
axis line style={->},
ymin=-0.5, ymax = 2.5,
xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
axis equal image
]
\draw (axis cs:1.25,1.25) circle [blue, radius=0.5];
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node[above left] {$a$};
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node (a) {$\bullet$};
\draw [->] (axis cs:1.25,1.25)  -- node[pos = 0.5, below] {$\delta$} (axis cs:1.75,1.25) ;

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ xshift=7cm,
ticks=none,
axis lines = middle,
axis line style={->},
ymin=-0.5, ymax = 2.5,
xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
axis equal image
]
\draw (axis cs:1.25,1.25) circle [blue, radius=0.5];
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node[above] {$a$};
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node(b){$\bullet$};
\draw [->] (axis cs:1.25,1.25)  -- node[pos = 0.5, below] {$\delta$} (axis cs:1.75,1.25) ;

\end{axis}

\draw[->](a)to[bend left](b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know of the xshift command before.

Comment: `pgfploots` is based on `tikz`, so it load it , i.e it is necessary to load `tikz` again. for `pgfplots` is fine to defined used version. for example after `1.11` you can write coordinates in diagram  as `(1.25,1.25)` .

Comment: @AndréC while using multiple axis, it is better to use `anchor` and `at` as suggested by Stefan in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464661/fill-between-breaks-suddenly.

Answer (score 4):

In the video it seems that the points also get accessed from outside, which means you might need `remember picture` anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}[ 
ticks=none,
axis lines = middle,
axis line style={->},
ymin=-0.5, ymax = 2.5,
xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
axis equal image
]
\draw (axis cs:1.25,1.25) circle [blue, radius=0.5];
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node[above left] {$a$};
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node{$\bullet$};
\draw [->] (axis cs:1.25,1.25)  -- node[pos = 0.5, below] {$\delta$} (axis cs:1.75,1.25) 
coordinate(d1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}[ 
ticks=none,
axis lines = middle,
axis line style={->},
ymin=-0.5, ymax = 2.5,
xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
axis equal image
]
\draw (axis cs:1.25,1.25) circle [blue, radius=0.5];
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node[above left] {$a$};
\draw[color=blue] (axis cs:1.25,1.25) node{$\bullet$};
\draw [->] (axis cs:1.25,1.25)  -- node[pos = 0.5, right] {$\delta$} 
(axis cs:1.25,0.75) coordinate(d2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{On the left, our point is on the
\tikzmarknode{D1}{right} while it is on the \tikzmarknode{D2}{bottom} in the
right figure. }
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,-latex] (D1) to[out=90,in=-90] (d1);
\draw[red,-latex] (D2) to[out=90,in=-90] (d2);
\draw[red,-latex] (d1) to[out=0,in=180] node[midway,above,sloped,fill=white,fill
opacity=0.6]{has moved}(d2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well I didn't even know you could do this but thank you so much I think this will explain the point I'm trying to make very well.

Comment: @JohnMiller I think the marmot finally found the crystal ball... Did you asked him?